# google plus hover bubble not showing up

Tags: google-plus, google-plus-one

The following code I tried in respect of google plus button on  a site,
the +1 part is working , but no hover bubble is showing up.

```
<html>
<head>
<!-- Place this tag where you want the +1 button to render. -->
<div class="g-plusone" data-annotation="inline" data-width="300" data-href="http://www.stackoverflow.com"></div>

<!-- Place this tag after the last +1 button tag. -->
<script type="text/javascript">
  (function() {
    var po = document.createElement('script'); po.type = 'text/javascript'; po.async = true;
    po.src = 'https://apis.google.com/js/plusone.js';
    var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(po, s);
  })();
</script>
</head>
</html>
```

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Is this the exact code that you're using? Or just a demo snippet? What language is your browser set to? By "hover bubble" do you mean the bubble that shows the text "Publicly recommend this as ____" or are you referring to the share dialog that displays after clicking the button?

Comment: Yup, this is the exact code, by hover bubble I mean the share dialog that also generates a sort of preview of the page, like in youtube, when u share a video on google plus.